# rails 3- undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

Thanks for helping. The  errors occurs during implementation `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I get

```
ActionView::Template:Error (undefined method 'events' for nil:class) & NoMethodError in app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #12.
```

See all files @ https://gist.github.com/726828

In summary the `User` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the `event` class. See the gist files. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what I see, you don't have `@user` in index (I suppose this is the `users/index`), this is why it raise an error when it tries to access `nil.events`.

In index you have `@users`. What you may want to do is to render a partial in `users/index` for each user with

```
<%= render :partial => "user", :collection => @users %>
```

and create a `users/_user.html.erb` where you put what you want to show.

By the way in your partial you will have access to `user` and not `@user`

sounds good to you?

Comment: Thanks @ecoologic, i will try and implement your suggestions.

Comment: Thaks again @ecoologic. I have made the changes you suggested and you can see the new files here https://gist.github.com/726898. However is till get thesame error. Do you think it has anything to do with trying to display data from the events table in the user/index. As i thought using accepts_nested_attributes_for is supposed to allow that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should access **user** without @, I suggest you to put a debugger line <% debugger %> and have a look at what you have and what you don't.

Comment: i am really grateful, everything now works fine, after following your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: very well, this is my first contribution to the community, happy to be helpful, have a good day